# Counting 3 digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics

How many  three digit numbers xyz with ('x' and 'Z') < y can be formed

a. Digits can be used only once.

b. Digits can be repeated.

Comment: are 00x,0xx allowed?

Comment: http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131014180831AAsz0XZ

Comment: @Chinny84 00x and 0xx not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are only interested in those numbers for which $x<y$ and $z<y,$ which means we cannot have $y=0.$ Moreover, we cannot have $x=0,$ and so we cannot allow $y=1,$ either.

If we allow repeats, then for each $n\in\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\},$ if we put $y=n,$ then there are $n-1$ possible choices for $x,$ and $n$ possible choices for $z.$ (Why?) Thus, there are $$\sum_{n=2}^9(n-1)n=\sum_{n=1}^8n(n+1)=\sum_{n=1}^8n^2+\sum_{n=1}^8n$$ different three-digit numbers meeting the conditions in this case. (If you know closed forms for the two sums on the far right, you should be able to take it from there.)

If we *don't* allow repeats, then for each $n\in\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\},$ if we put $y=n,$ then there are $n-1$ possible choices for $x,$ and *once we choose* such an $x,$ there will be $n-1$ possible choices for $z.$ (Why?) Thus, there are $$\sum_{n=2}^9(n-1)^2=\sum_{n=1}^8n^2$$ different three-digit numbers meeting the conditions in this case.